# Get the value from Model into List object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a student class with the following attributes and values. I am storing the first record of a student in a class into student object variable and how could I get the value of the first student  in to List

```
    List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
            new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Moin"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron"} 
        };

Student student = new Student();

 foreach (var students in class.students)
   {
       
       student = students
       break
        
   }

List<Student> firstStudent = new List<Student>();
```

How can I get the value of student from the class into firstStudent

Comment: studentList.FirstOrDefault() or with condition studentList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == student.StudentID)

Answer (score 2):

Using list, you can get first object with `.FirstOrDefault`

E.g.,

```
studentList.FirstOrDefault()
```

If you're using LINQ, you can get this with conditions, like filtering IDs with a Lambda expression; e.g.,

```
studentList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.StudentID == <value>) //replace <value> with appropriate value.
```

Your code will be like this:

```
    List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
            new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Moin"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron"} 
        };

 Student student = new Student();

 foreach (var students in class.students)
   {
       
       student = students
       break
        
   }

List<Student> firstStudent = studentList.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this.  use linq take to just get the first one from the list

here is the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/7eU8eZ

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
            new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Moin"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram"} ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron"} 
        };
        
        Class myClass = new Class(){
            ClassId = 1,
            Students = studentList
        };
        
        List<Student> firstStudent = 
        myClass.Students.OrderBy(x => x.StudentID).Take(1).ToList();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use index with list, it will create a list with one student

```
List<Student> firstStudent = new List<Student> { studentList[0] };
```

if you want just a first student

```
Student firstStudent = studentList[0] ;
```